# System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Parent]: [Parent]

Tags: visualforce, attachment

forAttachmentsCls class

```
        public class forAttachmentsCls{
            public Attachment file{set;get;}
            public forAttachmentsCls(){
            file = new Attachment();
            }

            public PageReference save(){

            TicketIntakeform__c acc = new TicketIntakeform__c();
            acc.name = 'test Attachment1';
            Insert acc;
            system.debug(file.Name);
            System.debug(acc.id);
            Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = acc.Id, name = file.Name, body=file.body) ;
            Insert file;
            return null;
            }
        }
```

forAttachmentsComp.component

```
        <apex:component controller="forAttachmentsCls" allowDML="TRUE">
          <apex:form>
           <apex:outputLabel escape="false" value="<b>Attachment</b>" for="attachId"/> 
           <apex:inputfile size="35" id="attachId"  value="{!file.body}" fileName="{!file.name}"/>
          <apex:commandButton styleClass="TabSpace" action="{!save}" value="Save" />
          </apex:form>
        </apex:component>
```

forAttachmentspage

```
    <apex:page>
    <c:forAttachmentsComp/>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting `file` object instance rather than attachment which doesn't have `parentId`.

Correct code is:

```
 Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = acc.Id, name = file.Name, body=file.body) ;
 Insert a;
```